# What shortcut can I use for comments in Xamarin - xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Note, I'm using Visual Studio 2022, on Windows.

Note2: I found CTRL + / in by googling, but it does not work.

I found a way to comment my code, but is there a keyboard shortcut for doing so?

For example, *This is a comment* from the code below?

```
      <Label Text="Ukupan iznos: " FontSize="30" Padding="0,2,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" 
    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
   <!-- This is a comment  -->
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 did you check the keyboard shortcuts docs? Look for "Comment selection"

Comment: I did, unfortunately, none of those work

Comment: Do you have ReSharper or some other plugin installed that alters the keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Ctrl + K, Ctrl + C. On windows, this is the shortcut for commenting code both for C# and XAML.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Ctrl + K + C for Commenting and for Uncommenting Ctrl + K + U